# How to parse string using php and store data in array

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have to parse a string composed by different values and then store the values that could be other strings or number in a array.

Example string of input:

```
$inputString = 'First key this is the first value Second second value Thirt key 20394';
```

I thought to create an array containing the key to find for subdivide my initial input string.
The array with the keywords to find it could be like the following:

```
$arrayFind = array ('First key', 'Second', 'Thirt key');
```

Now the idea is to cycle the $arrayfind from the beginning to the end and store in a new array the result. The resulting array that i need is like:

```
$result = array(
                'First key'=>'this is the first value', 
                'Second' => 'second', 
                'Thirt val' => '20394');
```

Anyone could help me? Thank you so much

Comment: That's a terrible input to work with. What if the first value is "the second lane left", or similar.

Comment: do you have a delimiter?

Comment: Convert your key list into a regex pattern `/First|Second|Third/` and use `preg_split()` for instance.

Comment: Yes, I know that is a terrible input. :( ..and I don't have delimiter. The only fixed values are the strings in the $arrayFind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$inputString = 'First key this is the first value Second second value Thirt key 20394';
$keys = ['First key', 'Second', 'Thirt key'];

$res = [];
foreach ($keys as $currentKey => $key) {
    $posNextKey = ($currentKey + 1 > count($keys)-1) // is this the last key/value pair?
                  ? strlen($inputString) // then there is no next key, we just take all of it
                  : strpos($inputString, $keys[$currentKey+1]); // else, we find the index of the next key
    $currentKeyLen = strlen($key);
    $res[$key] = substr($inputString, $currentKeyLen+1 /*exclude preceding space*/, $posNextKey-1-$currentKeyLen-1 /*exclude trailing space*/);
    $inputString = substr($inputString, $posNextKey);
}

print_r($res);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [First key] => this is the first value
    [Second] => second value
    [Thirt key] => 20394
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty code snippet to do that.

```
$inputString = 'First key this is the first value Second second value Thirt key 20394';
$tmpString = $inputString;
$arrayFind = array ('First key', 'Second', 'Thirt key');
foreach($arrayFind as $key){
    $pos = strpos($tmpString,$key);
    if ($pos !== false){
        $tmpString = substr($tmpString,0,$pos) . "\n" . substr($tmpString,$pos);
    }
}
$kvpString = explode("\n",$tmpString);
$result = array();
$tCount = count($kvpString);
if ($tCount>1){
    foreach ($arrayFind as $f){
        for ($i=1;$i<$tCount;$i++){
            if (strlen($kvpString[$i])>$f){
                if (substr($kvpString[$i],0,strlen($f))==$f){
                    $result[$f] = trim(substr($kvpString[$i],strlen($f)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Note: **This assumes there is no carriage return `\n` in the input string**

This may not be the most elegant way to do this. Also note if there is duplication of the key in the string this will take the last value.